# How to position buttons - java

Tags: java, button, position

I am trying to code a card game in java in which i need to position some buttons below the cards. i have looked into layout managers but i don't know exactly how to use them in the context i'm trying too.
My code is as follows(i also have a card class but that is working fine):

```
public class Elevens extends Frame implements MouseListener, ActionListener
{
    private BufferedImage  buffer;`
    Graphics2D h;
    private ArrayList<card> randDeck;
    private Random generator;
    private card currentStuff[] = new card[9];
    private ArrayList<card> deck;
    private boolean card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6, card7, card8, card9;
private JButton replace;

public Elevens()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Elevens");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    generator  = new Random();
    deck = new ArrayList<card>();
    randDeck = new ArrayList<card>();
    addMouseListener(this);
    replace = new JButton("Replace");
    replace.setActionCommand("replace");
    replace.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(replace);
    card1 = false;
    card2 = false;
    card3 = false;
    card4 = false;
    card5 = false;
    card6 = false;
    card7 = false;
    card8 = false;
    card9 = false;
    for(int i = 1; i < 53; i++)
    {
        card c = new card();
        if(i < 14)
        {
            c.setSuit('S');
            c.setValue(i);
            deck.add(c);
        }
        else if(i < 27 && i >= 14)
        {
            c.setSuit('D');
            c.setValue(i - 13);
            deck.add(c);
        }
        else if(i < 40 && i >= 27)
        {
            c.setSuit('C');
            c.setValue(i - 26);
            deck.add(c);
        }
        else
        {
            c.setSuit('H');
            c.setValue(i - 39);
            deck.add(c);
        }
    }
    while(deck.size() > 0)
    {
        int index = generator.nextInt(deck.size());
        randDeck.add(deck.get(index));
        deck.remove(index);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        currentStuff[i] = randDeck.get(i);
        randDeck.remove(i);
    }

}
public static void main(String[]arg)
{
    Elevens e = new Elevens();

    e.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
     {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
     });
    e.show();
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    h = (Graphics2D)g;
    g.setColor(new Color(0, 51, 25));
    g.fillRect(100, 300, 500, 500);
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        int x = (i * 100) + 150, y = 360;
        card c = currentStuff[i];
        if(i > 2)
        {
            x = (i - 3) * 100 + 150;
            y = 470;
        }
        if(i > 5)
        {
            x = (i - 6) * 100 + 150;
            y =  580;
        }
        c.drawCard(x, y, 80, 100, g, this);
    }
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    h.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
    if(card1)
    {
        g.drawRect(150, 360, 80, 100);
    }
    if(card2)
    {
        g.drawRect(250, 360, 80, 100);
    }
    if(card3)
    {
        g.drawRect(350, 360, 80, 100);
    }
    if(card4)
    {
        g.drawRect(150, 470, 80, 100);
    }
    if(card5)
    {
        g.drawRect(250, 470, 80, 100);
    }
    if(card6)
    {
        g.drawRect(350, 470, 80, 100);
    }
    if(card7)
    {
        g.drawRect(150, 580, 80, 100);
    }
    if(card8)
    {
        g.drawRect(250, 580, 80, 100);
    }
    if(card9)
    {
        g.drawRect(350, 580, 80, 100);
    }
}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
{
}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
{
}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    int x = e.getX(), y = e.getY();
    if( x >= 150 && y >= 360 && x < 230 && y < 460)
    {
        if(card1)
        {
            card1 = false;
        }
        else
        {
            card1 = true;
        }
    }
    if( x >= 250 && y >= 360 && x < 330 && y < 460)
    {
        if(card2)
        {
            card2 = false;
        }
        else
        {
            card2 = true;
        }
    }
    if( x >= 350 && y >= 360 && x < 430 && y < 460)
    {
        if(card3)
        {
            card3 = false;
        }
        else
        {
            card3 = true;
        }
    }
    if( x >= 150 && y >= 470 && x < 230 && y < 570)
    {
        if(card4)
        {
            card4 = false;
        }
        else
        {
            card4 = true;
        }
    }
    if( x >= 250 && y >= 470 && x < 330 && y < 570)
    {
        if(card5)
        {
            card5 = false;
        }
        else
        {
            card5 = true;
        }
    }
    if( x >= 350 && y >= 470 && x < 430 && y < 570)
    {
        if(card6)
        {
            card6 = false;
        }
        else
        {
            card6 = true;
        }
    }

    if( x >= 150 && y >= 580 && x < 230 && y < 680)
    {
        if(card7)
        {
            card7 = false;
        }
        else
        {
            card7 = true;
        }
    }
    if( x >= 250 && y >= 580 && x < 330 && y < 680)
    {
        if(card8)
        {
            card8 = false;
        }
        else
        {
            card8 = true;
        }
    }
    if( x >= 350 && y >= 580 && x < 430 && y < 680)
    {
        if(card9)
        {
            card9 = false;
        }
        else
        {
            card9 = true;
        }
    }
    repaint();
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String action = e.getActionCommand();
    if(action.equals("replace"))
    {
        if(card1)
        {

        }


        card1 = false;
        card2 = false;
        card3 = false;
        card4 = false;
        card5 = false;
        card6 = false;
        card7 = false;
        card8 = false;
        card9 = false;
    }
}
```

}`

im not finished coding my button but i'd like to be able to position it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate the logic of your custom painting from the logic of...everything else.

- Don't override `paint` of top level containers like `JFrame`.  Apart from the fact that they are not double buffered, you will end up painting under the frame decorations and over the top of the child components.  When a opaque child component is updated, the parent container will not be notified, this means any painting your relying on your frame to perform will not be updated.  Instead, create a custom component, extending from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method and put your custom painting here.
- Separate the game logic from the view.  Use some kind of model, with which you can interact with and which can provide notifications to the various views of the game.  This improves the communication channels and decouples your code.

Create an instance of a `JFrame` and add your an instance of your custom panel to it.  Create an instance of something like `JPanel`, set it's layout to something like `FlowLayout` and add your `JButton`s to it.  Place this (button) panel to the `SOUTH` position of the frame, for example...

```
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

`JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default.

Comment: so in my main i should do something more like this?'public static void main(String[]arg)
 {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Elevens");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(true);   
  Elevens e = new Elevens();
  e.setSize(900, 900);
  e.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
         {
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
          {
           System.exit(0);
          }
         });
       e.show();
 frame.add(e);
 }'

Comment: You can use JFrame#setDfaultCloseOperation and pass it JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE which will close the JVM when the window is closed so you don't need the window listener, but yes, that's the idea